# Why does the below SPICE simulation show an initial current even before the voltage source is applied?

Tags: mosfet, ltspice, simulation, powermosfet

LT-spice simulation is showing a sudden jump in MOSFET current from 0 to 5mA at t=0. What would be the explanation for this? Is it a tool issue?

[image]

[image]

All the capacitor initial voltages (C2, C1 and C4) are set to 0.

[image]

The initial 5mA is seen to be flowing through MOSFET M2 and C4. How can MOSFET conduct this mA current without the gate being turned on? More surprisingly before the input voltage is ramped up!!

Current through C2 seems to be ramping up at the same rate as input voltage.
[image]

Comment: The 'startup' means that independent sources are ramped on during the first 20μs of the simulation. Does that help any?

Comment: My first idea would be parasitic drain capacitance charging

Comment: @Jonk: Yes, How can simulation show an initial current when there the stimulus is zero?

Comment: @Lorenzo: Even for parasitic capacitance charging, we need the voltage to be applied, right?

Comment: @DivyaK.S well, yes. Ohm's law requires a voltage to make some current. Or maybe is simply an integration glitch of ltspice, since an empty ideal capacitor can sink an infinite amount of current from an infinitesimal amount of voltage

Comment: Look at the gate voltage with respect to the source.

Comment: @Andy Akka:  Vgs is not crossing the threshold. The Vgs plot is not added in question, but the condition is already explained in question body.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no glitch, it's the result of differentiation for the combined effect of the parasitic capacitances. In this case, if you modify the `.MODEL` to have `Cjo=0 Cgs=0`, you'll see that the effect vanishes. Even more, if you add a `1n` cap externally across the DS and plot the current through it, you'll see that the current has the same "jump":

[image: parasitics]

The value is `1.01n` because the current for `1n` is `1.4m`, which makes the plot look like the current is part of the axes (visual tweak, nothing else).

You can also try `uic` instead of `startup`, and then you'll see kA at play. That's because `startup` ads a fixed 20 μs ramp to the sources, while `uic` makes it relative to the time step (e.g. as small as possible), thus the slopes are magnitudes in difference (in this case).

Comment: But why would the current remain more or less constant and not ramp us ( just as the input voltage) is still open.

Comment: @DivyaK.S Why should it? The Vgs is still not enough, so it's not conducting. If you simulate for 50 us, you'll see it does. Unless I misunderstand when you want it to conduct.

Comment: @ACC  oh ya right. The parasitic capacitor ( Cds) would keep charging to an equilibrium voltage ( as long as Vgs is less than Vth) depending the values of C3 and C4. I think whether the current would remain constant or ramp  (increase/decrease) depends on ramp rate of input voltage and RC time constant.

Comment: @ACC  Why is the MOSFET channel conducting ( black curve) 1mA of current when Vgs has not reached the threshold? 

Datasheet doesn't mention the info completely.
Zero gate voltage drain current : 10uA

Comment: https://www.onsemi.com/products/discrete-power-modules/mosfets/fqb55n10

Comment: @DivyaK.S Have you tried setting to zero other capacitances in the `.MODEL`? Like, say, `Cgdmin, Cgdmax`?

Comment: @ACC. Thanks a lot. Now the current is zero till Vgs> Vgs(th)

Comment: @DivyaK.S I can only assume you're after a "what if" case because, if you do, indeed, set all the capacitances to zero, then you will no longer have a MOSFET, but some device impersonating a crippled MOSFET. If you wanted to see a quasi-real behaviour (to the extent of how real enough the circuit is modelled -- transistor, traces, parasitic capacitances, imperfect source, temperature, etc), then you should let the `.MODEL` untouched (or improve, but not disable).

Answer (score 0):

Part of this seems to be zoom-in issue. The current is increasing post the voltage is ramping up ( to mV level).

[image]